# Duplicate print composer or use template?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I want to duplicate a print composer in a project to use with a different atlas coverage layer but I am having problems generating the atlas.

I have tried to both duplicate the print composer in the composer manager and loading from a template but neither method would generate the atlas. I'm getting the error message:

`no matching atlas features found`

I have used the same atlas settings successfully in another print composer (using the same data sets) so I know it should work.

Obviously, I could set up the print composer from scratch again but I want to keep the exact layout. It seems like QGIS is having a problem 'refreshing' the atlas coverage layer. Has anyone else encountered this? or have suggestions as to how I can get it to recognise the new atlas layer?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and the cause was the shape file for the atlas being on a shared drive and my computer disconnecting from the shared drive via VPN.  I just had to re-add the file from the shared location and it worked fine.  To prevent this from happening I just have to close QGIS before I disconnect from the VPN.